# geom_line connects dots on the wrong axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider

```
data <- data.frame(A=runif(10), B=runif(10), Height=c(1:10))
library(reshape)
melted <- melt(data, id.vars="Height")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(melted, aes(value, Height)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=c(1:10)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")+
  geom_line(aes(group=variable))
```

geom_line is connecting the dots along the x-axis, but i would like it to connect the dots on the y-scale, to show the Height profile of my data. I was trying `coord_flip()` and exchange the `aes(x,y)` arguments, but that doesnt work with the scale argument in facet_wrap.

---

Side question:
In

```
scale_y_reverse(breaks=c(1:10)) +
```

i cannot exchange `c(1:10)` with `Height`, as the object is not found. This is odd, as it worked in my real life data.

Comment: Have you tried using `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`? It does require your data to be in order, however.

Comment: concerning the scale question, use:   `scale_y_reverse(breaks=melted$Height)`

Comment: "Height" is a string and will only work if that function has allowed it.

Comment: (Also, `c(1:10)` is equivalent to `1:10`.)

Comment: geom_path with rearranging the data[rev(rownames(data)),] was doing the trick. Maybe @sebastian-c wants to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_line` joins lines up from the minimum x to maximum. In order to get the lines drawn in a different order, you need to use `geom_path`.

```
ggplot(melted, aes(value, Height)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=c(1:10)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")+
  geom_path(aes(group=variable))
```

[image: Pretty plot]